# No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?

Tags: javascript, express, stripe-payments

I was writing a stripe webhook that would be called when a payment would be compleated. The problem is that when I try to check the signature I keeps giving me this error no matter what:

```
{"type":"StripeSignatureVerificationError","raw":{"message":"No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?
```

This is my code:

```
app.post("/webhook",express.raw({type: "*/*"}),async (request, response) => {
const payload = request.body;
const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];

let event;
// console.log(payload)
try {

  event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
    JSON.stringify(payload),
    sig,
    process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET
  );
} catch (err) {
  return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
}


if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
    // Retrieve the session. If you require line items in the response, you may include them by expanding line_items.
    const sessionWithLineItems = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
      event.data.object.id,
      {
        expand: ["line_items"],
      }
    );
    const lineItems = event;

    // Fulfill the purchase...
  }

response.status(200).end();
```

}
);

I already made sure to remove a global middleware bat I keep having this error.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed two differences between your code and the example code in Stripe's [webhook endpoint builder](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart?lang=node)

1. Try use `express.raw({type: 'application/json'})` instead of `express.raw({type: '*/*'})`
2. Remove the `JSON.stringify` when passing payload to `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent`

Let me know if it works after making above two changes.